# ObjectQuery<T> does not work in Entity Framework! Any suggestion what to use insted of

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2017, linq-to-entities, objectquery

I have struggled with `ObjectQuery`, but then I found out that it is only used in earlier versions of Visual Studio. I don't know what to use and how to use it in Visual Studio 2017. Can somebody help!? As you can see I'm using Entity Framework. I have read something about query but I don't know it is possible to use something else then that.

```
    namespace POSsytemFlamenca
    {
        public partial class LaFlamencaPSO : Form
        {
            private BindingList<TblProduct> products = new BindingList<TblProduct>();
            private FlamencaProEntities1 cse = new FlamencaProEntities1();

            public LaFlamencaPSO()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                listProductChosen.DataSource = products;
                listProductChosen.DisplayMember = "Description";
                CreateTabbedPanel();
                AddProductsToTabbedPanel();

            }

            private void AddProductsToTabbedPanel()
            {
                int i = 1;

                foreach (TabPage tp in tabControl1.TabPages)
                { 
                    // this is the problem
                    ObjectQuery<TblProduct> filteredproduct = new ObjectQuery<TblProduct>("SELECT VALUE P FROM TblProducts AS P WHERE P.ProductType = " + i.ToString(), cse);

                    FlowLayoutPanel flp = new FlowLayoutPanel();
                    flp.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

                    foreach (TblProduct tprod in filteredproduct)
                    {
                        Button b = new Button();
                        b.Size = new Size(100, 100);
                        b.Text = tprod.Description;
                        flp.Controls.Add(b);
                    }

                    tp.Controls.Add(flp);
                    i++;
                }
            }

            private void CreateTabbedPanel()
            {
                foreach (TblProductType pt in cse.TblProductTypes)
                {
                    tabControl1.TabPages.Add(pt.ProductType.ToString(), pt.Description);
                }
            }

            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                TblProduct p = new TblProduct() { Description = "Product A", 
                Price = 1.99M };
                products.Add(p);
            }

            private void FormtListItem(object sender, ListControlConvertEventArgs e)
            {
                string currentDescription = ((TblProduct)e.ListItem).Description;
                string currentPrice = string.Format("{0:C}",((TblProduct)e.ListItem).Price);
                string curretDescriptionPadded = currentDescription.PadRight(30);

                e.Value = curretDescriptionPadded + currentPrice;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try base methods of Linq:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/basic-linq-query-operations

or

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg509017.aspx